# java synchronization holding on to an object for specified interval of time

Tags: java, multithreading

In java can a thread hold on to an object for some specified interval of time ? For example, Suppose i have the following code:

```
package test;

class Thread1 implements Runnable {
    private int balance;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
    {
        increment();

        System.out.println("The bal by "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+balance);
    }
    }

    public synchronized void increment()
    {
        int i=balance;
        balance =i+1;
    }


}
```

Main class:

```
package test;

public class MainC {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Thread1 job=new Thread1();
    Thread a =new Thread(job);
    Thread b=new Thread(job);
    a.setName("Thread a");
    b.setName("Thread b");
    a.start();
    b.start();

}
}
```

Now, i want thread 1 to hold the lock on to the increment method till i==10 and don't want thread 2 to access the increment method! Is it possible!??

Comment: What do you want to happen after i == 10?

Comment: after i==10, thread b should take over accessing the value of "balance" updated by a.. then after i==25 again a should take over accessing the value of "balance" updated by b!

Comment: Do you have a general rule or are just 10 and 25 arbitrary?

Comment: arbitrary ! no general rule!

Comment: There are lots of ways of accomplishing this, but hard to do a good example without knowing the intention.

Comment: How come there's no general rule? If you don't have a general rule why then do you want the threads to switch control? Is it some kind of dynamic rule? Or why won't you just describe the actual motivation as Mattias suggested?

Comment: And... Have a look at [Condition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) API

Comment: Why do you need two threads for this? Just serialize everything in a single thread.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to being a method modifier, `synchronized` can be used on any standalone block of code.  For instance:

```
synchronized (this) {
    doStuff();
    doMoreStuff();
}
```

In your case, you can split up your loop into two loops, and place the first loop inside a `synchronized` block.

Comment: didn't you mean to put `doMoreStuff()` outside the `synchronized` block?

Comment: When you serialize processing like this, you don't even need synchronization. (Granted, OP's processing sounds like it _should_ be serialized.)